# c++ simple references type function

Tags: c++, function, reference, parameters

```
int& lameness()
{
    int h=66;
    return h;
}
int main()
{

    int c;
    c = lameness();
    cout<<"c is "<<c<< endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this work? int h is a local variable and shouldnt h be destroy once it exits function scope?

If i change my function to this it works without warning. Is this safer in any way?
:

```
int& lameness()
{
    int h=66;
    int &a = h;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. But the wonderful thing about undefined behavior is that what actually happens is... undefined. Destroying an `int` actually doesn't involve doing anything at all, so if nothing reuses that spot on the stack, the value is going to still be there. That's what makes this kind of thing so frustrating -- often it seems to work, until you make some small, seemingly unrelated change and it stops working!

Answer (score 2):

It works by coincidence, check this:

- http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t285367-return-reference-to-local-variable.html

Basically, it returned the right value due to the memory still being set to that value. Sometimes in the future, that might not be the case. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work.  It is undefined behavior.  Your skepticism was right on: the `lameness` function is an error, and some compilers would flag it as such.  Nonetheless, a compiler may be "conforming" and still "allow" this code...such is the "lameness" of C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is destroyed.  It happens to work because memory that h was stored in hasn't been overwritten by the time you print the value.

Answer (score 1):

It only works for you by coincidence, and because your code takes a copy of the value in the reference before doing anything else.  It is not guaranteed to work.

You could see it failing with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int& lameness()
{
    int h=66;
    return h;
}
int main()
{
    int &c = lameness();
    cout << "c is " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, I had to ignore compilation warnings:

```
x.cpp: In function ‘int& lameness()’:
x.cpp:5:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘h’ returned [enabled by default]
x.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
x.cpp:12:28: warning: ‘h’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

The output was:

```
c is 0
```

This happens because by the time `c` is passed to the I/O system, the space that was once `h` in `lameness()` has been reused for other variables, thus scratching the `66` that was stored in the space.  In fact, even your original code produces 0 on my machine.